# How to trigger a pull request to another branch when a pull request gets merged to a branch?

Tags: git, jenkins

In my project some times some people skip develop branch and directly merge to master . To ensure that develop and master branch is always in sync, how to create a reverse pull request from master to develop if a pull request is merged to master without develop . I would prefer solution through bitbucket if possible, otherwise in jenkins

Was reading different articles , not tried anything conclusive

Comment: are you asking for carrying out from within github or within bitbucket or from jenkins?  Tagging github and bitbucket is contradictory.  You can't really use both at the same time.

Comment: Looking out for a solution in bitbucket if possible, otherwise jenkins also works

Comment: Is this Bitbucket Cloud (bitbucket.org)? You've tagged Bitbucket Pipelines, which is a Cloud-only thing, but the correct answer will depend on whether you're on BB Cloud or a self-hosted version.

Comment: I have updated the tags

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you sure you really need the `develop` branch? If people merge directly to `master`, the benefits of `develop` as a staging ground are nullified. Also, if your team practices code reviews, perhaps the reviewers should pay attention to which branch the PR is to be merged.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub actually has its own API, with the help of [Create Pull Request](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/pulls/pulls?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-a-pull-request), you can create a Jenkins stage, which executes the curl command and opens a PR.

To only run this stage when merging a PR to master, you can check if your current branch is the master branch.
And to check if develop contains the changes merged into your master, you can try a git solution, something like this:

```
git branch --contains $COMMIT_ID
```